# Oracle SODA API for java - Exception - missing right parenthesis

Tags: java, oracle12c, soda

I am using Oracle SODA API for JAVA. I am using oracle 12c database. I am trying to fetch all records from the collection with desc sort on a field.

I have written the query like,

```
{ "$query" : {}, "$orderby" : { "LmCreatedOn" : -1}}
```

Here is java code,

```
//  connection code goes above
 final OracleDocument document = db.createDocumentFromString("{ \"$query\" : {}, \"$orderby\" : { \"LmCreatedOn\" : -1}}");

            final OracleCursor cursor = db.openCollection(SC_LMS_ADMIN_COURSE).find().filter(document).getCursor();

            List<JsonNode> listDto = new ArrayList<JsonNode>();

            while(cursor.hasNext()) {
                final OracleDocument doc = cursor.next();
                listDto.add(JacksonUtils.getObjectMapper().readTree(doc.getContentAsString()));
             }
```

But I am getting an exception,

> oracle.soda.rdbms.impl.SODAUtils$1OracleSQLException
>       at oracle.soda.rdbms.impl.SODAUtils.makeExceptionWithSQLText(SODAUtils.java:112)
>       at oracle.soda.rdbms.impl.SODAUtils.makeExceptionWithSQLText(SODAUtils.java:75)
>       at oracle.soda.rdbms.impl.OracleOperationBuilderImpl.getResultSet(OracleOperationBuilderImpl.java:684)
>       at oracle.soda.rdbms.impl.OracleOperationBuilderImpl.getResultSet(OracleOperationBuilderImpl.java:655)
>       at oracle.soda.rdbms.impl.OracleOperationBuilderImpl.getCursor(OracleOperationBuilderImpl.java:702)
>       at com.cisco.salesconnect.lms.SCLmsServiceHandler.getLMSCourses(SCLmsServiceHandler.java:198)
>       at com.cisco.salesconnect.lms.SCLmsService.getLMSCourses(SCLmsService.java:98)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   **Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis**
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:774)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:925)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1111)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4845)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1501)
>       at oracle.soda.rdbms.impl.OracleOperationBuilderImpl.getResultSet(OracleOperationBuilderImpl.java:665)
>       ... 52 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by following way,

According to [oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adsdi/soda-filter-specifications-reference.html#GUID-8AD6237B-860C-43A7-B6B7-5C8328784322)

> If you use Oracle Database Release 12c (12.1.0.2) then you must specify either $scalarRequired or $lax; otherwise a syntax error is raised.

As I am using Oracle Database Release 12c (12.1.0.2). I was using the query json without `$scalarRequired`. That's why it is throwing a syntax error.

The updated query is,

```
{ \"$query\": {}, \"$orderby\" : { \"$fields\" : [{ \"path\" : \"LmCreatedOn\", \"datatype\" : \"varchar2\", \"order\" : \"desc\"}], \"$scalarRequired\" : true }}
```

Here I have updated query format as well according to oracle doc. I have provided some extra `fields` with extra details. This feature is present into lastest `soda jar 1.1.0`